# Link ActionSheet button to TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I have an action sheet that pops up on a view controller. That action sheet has 3 buttons, "Choose Existing Icon", "Take Picture", and Cancel.

I have the Take Picture button working just fine. However, I want the Choose Existing Icon button to link to a UITableViewController that has a list of premade icons that I will have seeded the application with. How do I go about linking the button to the table of icons?

I have tried this in the clickedAtButtonIndex method,

```
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Choose Existing Icon"])
{
    IconViewController *iconPicker = [[IconViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:iconPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But this crashes. I want it to let the user see a table of icons and select one. Then have that icon show up in a UIImageView on the original controller.

Thanks for any help

EDIT

I'll change to buttonIndex, thanks for the tip on that. I followed a tutorial and didn't think much about it.

When I run the code as it is here, I get this error when I tap the "Choose Existing Icon" button.

2013-10-01 13:06:18.680 CardMinder[594:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView            _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:6235
2013-10-01 13:06:18.684 CardMinder[594:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from    tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Why don't u use index? if(buttonIndex == 0) // choose existing etc

Comment: I can't see a crash here, can you post the stack trace and the actual exception? My bet is that you're doing something wrong in the table view, and it's not linked to the action sheet at all. And Injectios is correct, you should really be using button indexes. Right now you must have the string in two places, which means when you decide to change the copy, you'll need to remember to change it or you'll create a bug.

Comment: I have changed to buttonIndex and I posted the error that I get. If you need anything else posted just ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for calling functions at button touchs in uiactionsheet similar to uialertview

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet/ ..... read this blog

Comment: Would you happen to know what that method is? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: -(void) actionsheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    //u need to change 0 to other value(,1,2,3) if u have more buttons.then u can check which button was pressed.

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        [self submitData];


    }



}